# Downloading image from Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, download

I would like to download an image from GEE to ArcGIS, with all information (coordinate, pixel value). I am trying but I couldn't.

How can I to do that?

I got this message:

```
Error: Image.clipToBoundsAndScale, argument 'input': Invalid type.
  Expected type: Image<unknown bands>. Actual type: ImageCollection.
```

This is the example of what I want to download (image)

[image]

This is my code:

```
var point = ee.Geometry.Point([-46.633286, -23.550510]);

// generate a buffer distance list
var distance_list = ee.List.sequence({
    start: 1000,
    end: 50000,
    step: 1000
});

var buffer_func = function (distance) {
    // new feature containing the buffer
    return ee.Feature(point.buffer(distance), {});
}

var buffers = ee.FeatureCollection(distance_list.map(buffer_func));

var clipToCol = function (image) {
    return image.clip(buffers)
}; /////////////////////////////

var AOD = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD19A2_GRANULES')
    .select('Optical_Depth_055')
    .filterDate('2019-05-13', '2019-05-28').map(clipToCol);
//.filterBounds(RMSP);

var viz = {
    min: 0,
    max: 350,
    palette: ['black', 'blue', 'purple', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']
};
Map.addLayer(AOD.mean(), viz, 'Optical Depth 055');

var outline = ee.Image().byte().paint({
    featureCollection: buffers, //////////////////////////
    color: 1,
    width: 1
});

Map.addLayer(outline, {
    palette: ['black']
}, 'buffers'); /////////////////////
Map.setCenter(-46.63203, -23.55221, 9);

Export.image.toDrive({
    image: AOD,
    description: 'image',
    scale: 1000,
    region: geometry
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`image` parameter causes the error. Its value should have been an `Image` object, but `AOD` is an `ImageCollection`. I guess, you would like to save `AOD.mean()`, which is an `Image`, to Drive. If so and if you want to get rid of that error, change `AOD` to, for example, `AOD.mean()` for `image` parameter.

```
Export.image.toDrive({
    image: AOD.mean(), // <--
    description: 'image',
    scale: 1000,
    region: geometry
});
```

`image.tiff` in ArcGIS:

[image]

Comment: Yes, It works perfectly. Thanks again for correct my description and help me.

Comment: I have one more question. I don't understan the scale. I know that in the description says min: -100 - max: 5000, and it has a scale (0.001). When I run the code, depends the scale the intensity of colors change. The question is, Could you please explain to me that?