# Error while exporting the TIFF format image in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

Error:

> ERROR---Error: Image.clipToBoundsAndScale, argument 'input': Invalid type. Expected type: Image. Actual type:
> ImageCollection. (Error code: 3)

THE SCRIPT:

```
Map.addLayer(roi)
Map.centerObject(roi, 10)
var img = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
              .filterDate('2021-10-01','2021-10-25')
              
              .filterBounds(roi);

var calcLSWI = function(image) {
  var lswi = image.expression(
       '(NIR - SWIR) / (NIR+SWIR)', {
      'NIR': image.select('B8').multiply(0.0001),
      'SWIR': image.select('B11').multiply(0.0001),
 }).rename('LSWI');
  return image.addBands(lswi);
}
var LSWI = img.map(calcLSWI).select('LSWI')
print(LSWI)
Map.addLayer(LSWI)
var Chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection: LSWI,
  regions: roi,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), //type of reduction. See ee.Reducers for other kinds of reductions
  seriesProperty: 'NAME'  //property of roi to display in map
})
  .setOptions({
    title: 'LSWI',
    vAxis: {title: 'LSWI', maxValue: 1, minValue: -1},
    hAxis: {title: 'date'},
  })

print(Chart)
Export.image.toDrive({
image: LSWI,
description: 'LSWI_VAISHALI',
folder: 'classification',
scale: 30,
fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
    });
```

[Link to code](https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/?scriptPath=users%2Fsinghsantosh7377%2Fproject%3ALSWI_CHART_TIME_SERIES)

Comment: You may want to check this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/397481/29431

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty self-explanatory. You can only export a single image at the time, but instead you are trying to export an imageCollection made up of 20 separate images. You can either export them individually with a loop or calculate a mean or median and export that.